# How to get all the combinations of three lists in java?

Tags: java, list, set, combinations

I have a situation where I have to check all the possible answers for a series of questions on a website. All the options are of type checkbox.

For example: (Q: question, A,B,C: option)

Q1: A1 A2 A3 A4

Q2: B1 B2 B3

Q3: C1 C2

So I need to check all the combinations like:

A1B1C1, A1B1C2, A1B2C1, A1B2C2 and so on....

And also

A1A2B1C1, A1A2B1C2, A1A2B1B2C1, A1A2B1B2C2, A1A2B2B3C1, A1A2B2B3C2, A1A2B1B3C1, A1A2B1B3C2 and so on

A1A2B1B2B3C1, A1A2B1B2B3C2, A1A2B1B2B3C1C2 and so on.

Thank you.

Comment: Run nested for loops,though this is a bad idea

Comment: StackOverflow isn't for code requests. Show what youve tried, or at least show some research effort

Answer (score -1):

Run 3 nested for loop or recursion below is an example of how you could do it

```
String[] Q1 = {"A1", ... "An"};
String[] Q2 = {"B1", ... "Bn"};
String[] Q3 = {"C1", ... "Cn"};
Set<String> combination = new HashSet<>();

for (String q1: Q1) {
   for (String q2: Q2) {
      for (String q3: Q3) {
        combination.add(q1 + q2 + q3)
    }
  }
}
```

if you want even more combination you could do a recursion